# Мясо говядины

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сплошь и рядом сейчас можно увидеть ценники "Мясо говядины". Или я чего-то не понимаю, или это все-таки неправильно.
Скажите, я прав?
Спасибо

Comment: Dear Tao. Ваше первое предложение ложно.

Answer (score 5):

Нет, это как минимум избыточно. Говядина - это и так мясо.
Можно сказать "говяжье мясо", да и то не слишком изящно будет, когда есть просто "говядина".

Answer (score 2):

Мясо говядины - неверное сочетание.

МЯСО - это туша (часть туши) животных, а также приготовленное из туш животных блюдо, кушанье. ГОВЯДИНА - это мясо коровы, быка, вола. Также в разговорной речи говядину иногда называют мясом, например: купить мяса и свинины.

Answer (score 2):

нет такого животного - говядина. Есть корова. Значит, либо говядина, либо мясо коровы. 
И вообще, полагаться на грамотность продавцов говядины не стоит)))

Answer (score 0):

Буквально сегодня увидела такой ценник.
Это потому, видать, что в определенных кругах говядина это не мясо, а отдельные скоты из племени крупных рогатых.